# Read error while reading data form Excel spreadsheet by using Perl

Tags: perl

What is this error? When I am trying to read data from Excel using Perl?

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/Read.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at read_data.pl line 4. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at read_data.pl line 4.
```

Answer (score 3):

It means `Spreadsheet::Read` module is not install in your system where you are executing your Perl script. Install that module.